# Contact Form Problems

Tags: jquery, forms

Trying to install this contact form:
http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/how-to-create-a-built-in-contact-form-for-your-wordpress-theme

I'm getting HUGE gaps between fields: http://themeforward.com/demo2/features/contact-form/

Any idea what the problem is?  I should be able to figure this one out after the problem is identified.

Comment: How about that `padding-bottom: 32767px;` in `#post_content ul li, #archive_content ul li, #content ul li (line 1260)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the markup, you have your `padding-bottom` set to **32767px**.

Take a look at these CSS class definitions:

```
#archive_content ul li, #content ul li {
    padding-bottom: 32767px;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this CSS rule in `style.css` (line 1260):

```
#post_content ul li, #archive_content ul li, #content ul li {
    padding-bottom: 32767px;
}
```

The `margin-bottom: -32767px;` *would* counteract that if it wasn't immediately superceded by `margin: 10px 0;`.

So, from that rule set, remove either:

- `margin: 10px 0`, *or*
- `padding-bottom: 32767px` *and* `margin-bottom: -32767px`